# No query results for model [App\Product], while getting all data from table laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to get data from the product table with a relationship with stock. But as a fresh instance, I have no data in the product and stock table. It showing me error "**No query results for model [App\Product]**"

My Controller

```
public function transaction()
{
    $viewdata["clients"] = Client::all();
    $products = Product::with('stock')->where('is_active', 1)
        ->orderBy('chemical_name')
        ->paginate(1000);
    $viewdata["products"] = $products;
    $viewdata["product_weights"] = ProductWeight::all();
    $viewdata["products_stock"] = Product::all();
    return view('transaction.index')->with($viewdata);
}
```

My View

```
<select class="form-control basic" name='product_names[]'>
     <option value="">Select</option>
       @if ($products->count() > 0)
          @foreach($products as $product)
             @if ($product->chemical_name !== "MIXED CHEMICAL")
              <option value='{{$product->id}}'>{{$product->chemical_name}}</option>
             @endif
          @endforeach
     @endif
    </select>
```

Please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Please attach complete controller code

Comment: i have attached my controller function, please take a look.

Comment: try to dump your products at the controller first using dd($products) what you get

Comment: As I mentioned that my product table is empty now. I don't have any product, still, I want to ignore this error show nothing in my view.

Comment: Paginate method shouldn't return error, It should return empty response when you have no data.

Comment: when I use dd($products), it also shows the same error. don't find any solution.

Comment: Try using get() instead of paginate and tell me what you get

Comment: same error showing. i don't find any idea why it shows this error whether it has any data or not?

Comment: Oh got the issue and solved it. thanks for your help. I was querying a product that is not on there. My fault.